# Weka não reconhecendo atributo no formato "date"

Tags: java, data, weka

Eu tenho um conjunto de tratamento e testes que criei com um programa em Java.

No cabeçalho, está assim:

```
*@attribute data date "yyyy-MM-dd"*
```

E entre outros atributos.

Um exemplo de uma linha dos dados é:

```
*@data

"2014-01-02",11.27,11.44,11.03,11.18,11.07,11.07,11.12,9419,2003400,2240946600,1*
```

Mas o estranho é que quando abro o arquivo `.arff` no Weka, a data fica classificada de forma bizarra, o gráfico gerado do atributo `data` fica entre intervalos nada a ver como *138862800000* e *1419904800000*.

Como resultado, não consigo classificar esse conjunto corretamente, ou ele joga tudo como sendo classe *1* ou classe *2*.

Como eu arrumo a data?

Comment: Olá Thiago, você teve algum sucesso? conseguiu resolver o problema? Estou iniciando meus estudos com o Weka.

Answer (score 1):

Está no formato de milessegundos, se você clicar em edit provavelmente vai aparecer a formatação da data correta, basicamente é um tipo float, e isso ocorre porque o WEKA trabalha com valores numéricos. Para contornar isso, você deverá realizar uma transformação dos dados através do filtro ChangeDateFormat (`filters->unsupervised->attribute->ChangeDateFormat`), escolha o índice do atributo(`attributeIndex`) e o formato (`dateFormat`), após clique em Ok e Apply. Para finalizar aplique o filtro `NunericToNiminal` para converter os dados para o tipo nominal.

Answer (score 0):

tudo bem? Cara, o weka vai exibir sim o timestamp da data naquela tela inicial. Experimenta rodar alguma coisa em cima do teu dataset, e veja como ele se comporta. Por exemplo: Rode um forecasting, veja que ele vai exibir as datas normalmente, como no arquivo ARFF especificado. Se ainda assim não funcionar, atualize a pergunta com a função que está tentando utilizar.